# Selecting at different column index for each row in tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, slice

I have a pytorch tensor

```
t = torch.tensor(
            [[1.0, 1.5, 0.5, 2.0],
             [5.0, 3.0, 4.5, 5.5],
             [0.5, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0]]
)
```

`t[:, [-1]]` gives me last column value of each row:

```
tensor([[2.0000],
        [5.5000],
        [2.0000]])
```

However, I want to slice values at different columns per row. For example, in `t` for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd row, I want to slice at 2, -1, 0 index respectively to get the following tensor:

```
tensor([[0.5],
        [5.5],
        [0.5]])
```

How can I do it in `torch`?

Answer (score 2):

```
t[[i for i in range(3)], [2, -1, 0]]
```

The list comprehension creates a list filled with row indexes, then you specify the column index for every row.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a torch function instead of the list comprehension: t[torch.arange(3), [2, -1, 0]]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
t = torch.tensor(
            [[1.0, 1.5, 0.5, 2.0],
             [5.0, 3.0, 4.5, 5.5],
             [0.5, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0]]
)
t
>tensor([[1.0000, 1.5000, 0.5000, 2.0000],
        [5.0000, 3.0000, 4.5000, 5.5000],
        [0.5000, 1.0000, 3.0000, 2.0000]])

rows = [0, 1, 2]
cols = [2, -1, 0]

t[rows, cols]
>tensor([0.5000, 5.5000, 0.5000])
```